# How to get Drupal cache key?

Tags: 8

If you have caching enabled in Drupal, instead of getting URLs like so:

```
image.png
```

You get:

```
image.png?itok=RANDOMNESS
```

What function would I need to call to get back the value = "RANDOMNESS"? I ask, because I want to cache other things using the same method Drupal does internally.

Any ideas?

Comment: That has nothing to do with caching, it's access protection for image styles. What do you want to protect, against what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `itok` is defined in ImageStyle@getPathToken entity when building the URL (ImageStyle@buildUrl):

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getPathToken($uri) {
    // Return the first 8 characters.
    return substr(Crypt::hmacBase64($this->id() . ':' . $this->addExtension($uri), $this->getPrivateKey() . $this->getHashSalt()), 0, 8);
  }
```